# 500 Internal Server error on find_or_create_by()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've set up a simple web-application with rails 4 and am struggling with a find_or_create_by.
Despite the entry being in my SQLite-database when executing the query manually it doesn't return anything.

This is the code in my controller:

```
login_as User.find_or_create_by(
    :user_id  => 20827
)
```

This is my application-controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :login_from_session

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end

  def login_as(user)
    raise user
    @current_user = user
    session[:current_user_id] = user.try(:id)
  end

  def login_from_session
    @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  end
end
```

This is the output on the webserver:

> User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>
> User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 20827 LIMIT 1
>
> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
>
> TypeError (exception class/object expected):
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `raise'
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `login_as'

The raise(user) on login_as() doesn't return an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be some error.You checked in console?

Comment: There is just a TypeError telling me that the "User" object I tried to retrieve from the database doesn't exist

Comment: No.It is telling that either an `object(instance variable)` or `exception class` is expected for `raise`. Try using `raise @current_user.inspect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError (exception class/object expected):
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `raise'
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `login_as'

Try using `raise @current_user.inspect` instead

```
def login_as(user)
    raise @current_user.inspect
    @current_user = user
    session[:current_user_id] = user.try(:id)
  end
```